meaning of 決める in もうダッシュ決めてたんだろ
so, I was listening to a song by そらる (an utaite/singer), called 自己採点 (link to the YouTube MV here). and the first line of the song left me kind of intrigued as to what 決める means there. the line here is:

キンコン鳴る4時20分の音でもうダッシュ決めてたんだろ

the キンコン鳴る4時20分の音で part is easy, it just means 'at the sound of [the bell] ringing ding-dong at 4:20', but what about もうダッシュ決めてたんだろ? 決める means 'to decide', which doesn't really make sense here. I had decided to run fast? I used to decide to run fast? it doesn't fit, I think. I thought that maybe it could be sense 4 from this dictionary, = 成功させる (like, ストライクを決める, to score a strike; シュートを決める, to score a goal), so something like... to "score" a dash? like, to run fast very well or doing it right after planning to do it?
but there's also another sense of 決める, like ～に決めている, which means 'to always do something', like

朝食はトーストとコーヒーに決めている
I always have coffee and toast for breakfast.

but I don't think that fits here either.
so, what does 決めてたんだろ mean here? and how would you translate that whole line?

https://best-kobetsu.co.jp/column/17621/ Although the meaning is a little different here, I think it should be sense4 "スポーツなどで、ある技を成功させる".

決める used in this way not only means "to succeed/finish/do" but also adds a certain sense of coolness or stylishness. The seventh definition in your link (かっこうよく着こなす) is loosely related.

ポーズを取る just means "to take a pose", while ポーズを決める means "to strike a pose (stylishly, like a star)". These are set phrases worth memorizing.
This type of 決める is also often used for actions that are socially bad but can be considered cool by delinquent people. For example, ドラッグを決める ("to shoot up drugs") and バックレを決める ("to skip out on work").
Sometimes, people even freely say something like ラーメンを決める to add some stylish, bold or hard-boiled atmosphere to the action.

So someone saying ダッシュを決める instead of ダッシュする is treating the dash as a cool (and possibly bad) action. Not sure how to translate this nicely into English...
Note that を is used instead of に in these examples. ～に決める is a much more elementary phrase. Since this usage is slangy, this type of 決める is commonly written with katakana (キメる), too.

thank you, thank you! I suspected this was what 決める meant there, because I had already seen it spelled in katakana like キメる for something that I thought was similar to this sense. I won't mark your answer with a check just yet, because I think someone might show up and translate it nicely into EN for me. but this helps me a lot with getting the meaning!
